# Android Studio doesn't accept "this" as LoaderCallBack argument inside OnRefreshListener

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout, android-loadermanager

I am trying to add Swipe Refresh Layout to my fragment. I am using AsyncTaskLoader to load data. While setting the Refresh Layout's OnRefreshListener, I want to restart the loader to load new data (or else should I do different thing) but I can't handle the loaderCallBacks argument. It gives error if I use "this". It says "Found OnRefreshListener, Required LoaderManager.LoaderCallback" object.
(I have my OnCreateLoader, OnLoadFinished and OnLoaderReset.)

Here is my code:

```
// class declaration
public class FragmentTopNews extends Fragment
    implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<NewsItem>>, NewsAdapter.OnItemClickListener{

...

if(activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()){
   LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();
   loaderManager.initLoader(NEWS_LOADER_ID, null,this);
   } 

    // SwipeRefreshlayout for refreshing the data
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.srl_refresher);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            mNewsAdapter.clearData();
            mNewsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
            // Here is the problem
            getLoaderManager().restartLoader(NEWS_LOADER_ID, null, this);
        }
    });
```

My second question is "getloaderManager()" term is strike-through telling me that it is deprecated. What can I do for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question:

When you set the listener, you made a new anonymous inner class instance of the `OnRefreshListener`, which means `this` is an instance of it, not your Fragment that's implementing `LoaderCallbacks`.

Use `FragmentTopNews.this` instead:

```
getLoaderManager().restartLoader(NEWS_LOADER_ID, null, FragmentTopNews.this);
```

For your second question:

`android.app.Fragment` and its related classes have been deprecated in API 28. You're supposed to use the `android.support.v4.app` versions instead. In other words, change your imports. You will have to also start using AppCompatActivity and `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

EDIT:

Seems the support docs are outdated. I had to actually go to [AOSP](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_support/blob/androidx-master-dev/fragment/src/main/java/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.java#L1048) to find this, but `Fragment#getLoaderManager()` is indeed deprecated. Use `LoaderManager.getInstance(Fragment)`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. First issue is solved. Coming to the second, I already use v4 versions of the library. (import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;)
What do you mean by "start using AppCompatActivity"? Extend the fragment to it? I tried, it gives error.

Comment: Are you sure this Fragment is a support Fragment? [getLoaderManager()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getLoaderManager()) isn't deprecated in the support library.

Comment: Yes I am sure. Here is the beginning.
...
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import java.util.List;
...
public class FragmentTopNews extends Fragment
        implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<NewsItem>>, NewsAdapter.OnItemClickListener{

Comment: Doesn't accept "Fragment" as an argument, requires (T owner) expression. 
 LoaderManager.getInstance(Fragment).initLoader(NEWS_LOADER_ID, null,this);

Comment: @HüseyinŞahin Fragment is the argument type. Just pass `this`.